# Vuex Store Thread-Safety

Tags: javascript, vuex

I need to perform a potentially longer task in an action which requires that there are no other writes to the accessed state variables.
Therefore, I need to know whether the actions are thread-safe and I can assume that there will be only one action executed at a given time or if I have to lock the critical parts.

To give a bit of background, I want to synchronize local data with a remote server and I need to make sure that the local data doesn't change while the synchronization is taking place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking for a way to lock, I found that Javascript in general doesn't interrupt synchronous code, therefore, the action has to run through before another one can be executed. Except for promises, of course (meaning other code may be executed before then is called if I'm not totally mistaken).
Unfortunately, I need to update the local data in promises, hence, I have to look for a way to lock changes until the promise was executed on a per data entry basis.